# Does parameters variation not update the builtin database?

Tags: anylogic

I notice that whenever I run a ParametersVariation model, the built-in database does not update... I have PLE, so there is no way for me to write my own database. I am currently able to pull data from various logs present in the database, but only from a normal simulation run. Is there a way to have the parameters variation write its data to the database after each simulation run?

I am currently running this code in After simulation run

```
Database myFile = new Database(this, "A DB from Excel", "C:/Users/Downloads/DataExport.xlsx");
ModelDatabase modelDB = getEngine().getModelDatabase();
modelDB.exportToExternalDB("flowchart_stats_time_in_state_log", myFile.getConnection(), "Sheet", false, true);
```

The export works perfectly. But the data never changes and this is confirmed by exporting a distribution from a histogram that changes with every simulation run. But for this export, its the same data as was written to the database from the last standard (non-parametersvariation) simulation run.

Comment: It should work fine, can you create a small reproducible example and show where in the process it is not working for you. 
My advice: use a txt file and you create on the simulation page pass it as a parameter to the simulation runs and have each of them write their data to it...

Comment: The thing is, when I conduct a parameters variation experiment, when I look to the built in database, the data does not change. No matter how many runs and iterations are conducted, the database tables remain the same as the last standard simulation I ran. The data in the built in database only seems to change when I run a standard simulation. I understand your solution with the txt file, however, if parameters variation can not update the database then it is irrelevant.

Comment: Write your required data directly to the txt file, skip the database... ;-)

Comment: But the required data is FROM the database. I am unaware on how to pull data like "flowchart_stats_time_in_state_log" to the extent in which the built-in db does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model log database tables aren't produced for multi-run experiments. It's not specifically stated anywhere, but they're designed more for testing/debugging (single runs of) models.

(Also, notice that the log tables don't have columns specifying a run ID or similar, so there's no way that you would have been able to distinguish rows for different runs anyway, even if there were rows written in multi-run experiments.)

Unfortunately, because they are one of the only ways to 'automatically' produce certain forms of output data (like the contents of datasets or histograms) many people try to use them for that (even though they have a pretty un-useful 'internal' format). In general you should write to your own internal database tables for any persistent outputs, where you can also govern whether you store outputs for multiple runs or not (which will require you to calculate some form of unique run IDs and use those in columns to differentiate outputs per run, plus have logic or UI elements to determine when the table data is cleared for a new run and when it isn't).

**NB**: Note that the kinds of data the model log tables (like `flowchart_stats_time_in_state_log` which you mention) create can in virtually all cases be determined and created 'manually' via your own model code. That table in particular has a large amount of detail on what's happened in each block and, in any given case, it's probably only a fraction of that data (or a simplification/aggregation of it) that you really want/need.

Comment: When you mean "write to my own database tables", do you mean using the Database block found in the Connectivity library because that is unavailable to me in PLE. If you are talking about another option, I would love to know! Thanks

Comment: No, I just mean inserting into the model's built-in database (and defining your own output tables there), which you can then automatically export to Excel at run-end. See the Working with Model Data --> Database section in the help.